# React loadStripe method not updating the element form on country wise selection

Tags: reactjs

I have different stripe accounts for different countries, So on dropdown selection I want to change stripe checkout/element form according to country wise selection as shown in picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPdJY.png)

```
// public_key is coming from backend API according to countries dropdown selection
stripePromise = loadStripe(public_key)
```

So when I pass stripePromise to stripe Elements then it's loaded only once according to my first selection from dropdown.

For suppose I selected the **United kingdom** from dropdown and it's showing checkout form for Uk, and if I changed the country from **United Kingdom** to **United States** than loadStripe method never updated it's checkout form and always showing **UK** checkout form.

So how can I reload my stripe elements according to different public keys?

PS: public key is always updating according to country wise selection.

PS: I'm using reactjs stripe package (@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2")

```
<Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
  <CheckoutForm ref={this.child} />
</Elements>
```

What should I do in that case, any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

I finally get the answer myself.

Simply just pass the key attribute with a unique id in the Elements component of the stripe and it will re render everytime according to latest stripe public key.

```
<Elements key={unique_key_number} stripe={this.state.loadstripe_promise}>
   <CheckoutForm ref={this.child} />
</Elements>
```